# Why i am not able to fetch the location in Simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4

Question it self explain the detail, but still i have explained about the question.

I am new to fetch the location of the current Application. I have build one application that gives me the Current location in Text View.

But while i run that application in to xcode 4.0, I can't see any location to be fetch.

As i refer many example, i am right in coding. But now i want to know is IPhone Simulator able to fetch the current location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iPhone simulator doesn't give the currentlocation.But It should be work in the Device.So try it on device.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I m trying a lot but not getting lat,lon. Now i come to know that the iPhone Simulator will not work for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you try it device current latitude and longitude will returns, but if you try it in simulator latitude=0 and longitude=0 will be return. Because user latitude and longitude is returns from GPS device which is in iPhone but not in simulator. So better you try it in device.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I got the Sollution why i am not getting the location. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`in view did load

```
locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    appDelegate.IsFromRefreshPosition=YES;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
geocoarder returns the plackmark of current location

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 

{   
    currentLocation = newLocation;
    [currentLocation retain];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
     NSLog(@"%f   %f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
     geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:currentLocation.coordinate];
     [geocoder setDelegate:self];
     [geocoder start];

}   

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"locationManager:%@ didFailWithError:%@", manager, error);
}
-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder1 didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    NSLog(@"The geocoder has returned: %@",[placemark addressDictionary]);
    NSLog(@"CountryName :",[[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"Country"]);
    NSLog(@"cityName :",[[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"City"]);
        NSLog(@"After SubLocality %@",Addressstr);

    }

}
-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder1 didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{   
    NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder:%@ didFailWithError:%@", geocoder, error);
}
```

ITS WORK IN DEVICE FINE WITH ME

Answer (score -2):

Following code will allow to show you user's current location;

```
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```